# django getting related objects

Tags: python, django

I've got a model that includes:

```
class Campaign(models.Model):
    campaign_name       = models.CharField(max_length=120) 
.
.
.

class Character(models.Model):
    name            = models.TextField(max_length=50)
.
.
.
    def __unicode__(self):
        return u'%s' % (self.name)

class Rank(models.Model):
    campaign_id     = models.ForeignKey('Campaign')
    character_id    = models.ManyToManyField(Character)
    rank           = models.IntegerField(blank=True)
.
.
.
```

In my template that shows all the details of the campaign I also want to include the characters and their rank for that specific campaign, I've tried the GenericRelation route and reverse traversal with no luck.  I'm on django 1.5.1

Comment: A tip for future use is install a pep-8 checker if you're using eclipse or enable it if you use Pycharm. Otherwise, read up on it, its a lifesaver!

Comment: It chokes on a lot of django specific things, but yes it's excellent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From this it looks like characters aren't related to a campaign directly, but only through their rank.  Correct?

In that case, given campaign `campaign`, then all of the ranks associated with the campaign are `campaign.rank_set` (you can change the name by specifying `related_name` on the rank's ForeignKey to campaign).

For each of the ranks you fetch like that, assuming you loop over the set and call individual ranks `rank`, you can find the set of characters with `rank.character_id` and loop over them just like you do with ranks.

If you have the character object and want to find all of the ranks associated with it, then you can do `character.rank_set`.

You should probably rethink your nomenclature, but I can't advise you on how to do that without knowing more about what a `rank` is for exactly and why it's related to the other models as it is.

Also, keep in mind that as it is right now, a character can have multiple ranks.  If you want characters to only have one rank, then you need to remove the ManyToMany field from rank and instead put a ForeignKey field to rank on character.

```
{% for rank in campaign.rank_set %}
  <p>Characters for {{ rank }}:</p>
  <ul>
    {% for character in rank.character_id %}
      <li>{{ character }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
  </ul>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Okay, sure.  I hesitated because I thought the OP would probably like to rethink naming and relationships, but here's an example with the model exactly as it is.

Comment: Rank is their standing in the current campaign (so yes they can have multiple ranks depending on the campaign, and the only tie between character and campaign is through rank).  This helps a lot, thanks!